# Default value of parameter not returned in Response Object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am learning WebServices using SpringBoot.

I came across this example [spring-actuator-service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/)

The console log states the following

```
2017-04-07 03:04:59.281  INFO 13024 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 9001 (http)
2017-04-07 03:04:59.290  INFO 13024 --- [           main] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 0
2017-04-07 03:04:59.548  INFO 13024 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 9000 (http)
2017-04-07 03:04:59.555  INFO 13024 --- [           main] hello.HelloWorldConfiguration            : Started HelloWorldConfiguration in 8.274 seconds (JVM running for 9.183)
```

When I ran the application as a spring boot application and entered the

http://localhost:9001/hello-world

The response that I get on the screen is as below.

```
{"timestamp":1491514947950,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/hello-world"}
```

can anyone help me understand why am I not getting the response as

```
{"id":1,"content":"Hello, Stranger!"}
```

Comment: The example mentions `curl http://localhost:9000/hello-world` to get the expected answer, but you apparently use the port 9001. Or is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Port 9001 is the *actuator* endpoint (health metrics and similar). Port 9000 is your application's content, where the `HelloWorldController` is. As mentioned in the documentation and by @Marc Tarin, use `http://localhost:9000/hello-world`.